# How do metal infused filaments work?

Tags: pla, post-processing, material, metal-printing, filled-pla

I am considering making modifications to my Ender 3 so I can print metal-infused PLA, but I'm somewhat unclear on how it works and how the PLA is supposed to be separated from the metal content in post-processing?

Comment: The title is not very clear, what do you mean by how they work? Filament is filament and a printer can print it. Are you e.g. hinting to very high metal content to post-process (sinter) to get metal parts? Is it the post-processing step you don't understand?

Comment: if you separate binder from infused metal, you will be left with metal dust, likely wasting printing efforts.  is that what you wish to do?  If so, you could try to melt or burn it out.

Comment: interesting, I was more just wondering how post-processing on it is done

Comment: @TristanAdams That depends on the application. Is it PLA with a little metal or is is metal powder with a binder. The latter printed objects need to be sintered in an oven at high pressure and temperature, not something you can generally do at home.